# Generating a random number and adding to an HTML argument's string

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a header image change randomly based on a random number being chosen.  This is the code I have right now, and it requires the entire  tag.

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/site_gfx/headers/header_<?php echo(rand(1,7)); ?>.png" width="980" height="230" alt="Example Site" />
```

Is there any reason it would be dying like it is?  Where the `<?php echo`  part is is the PHP code i'm using to generate the random number, and I'd like to include that into the string for the img src

Comment: are the photo's extention .png or .PNG? Could make a difference if case sensitive.

Comment: Is this a PHP page? Does it end with .php?

Comment: they're lowercase extensions, I checked.  And this is a .php page its on.

Comment: The PHP isn't generating the number, as such the image that would have the number is 404-ing and alt-text is showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The problem is I didn't realize the `<?php` area was running within an `echo` command (stupid little oversight on my part).  But modifying the `echo` statement that I was working with fixed it.

Thanks for the pointers, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

How's it dying? I'd try `print` or `echo` without parentheses, as I haven't seen `echo()` used before:

**print()**:

```
<?php print(rand(1,7)); ?>
```

**echo**:

```
<?php echo rand(1,7); ?>
```

Comment: no difference for print and echo to just spit out a simple text  of something. At least not in my experiences.

Comment: `print` is also not a function, but a struct, so `print X;` without parenthesis is 'better'.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you want to do this with PHP, it would probably be easier with javascript. try to remove the rand(1,7) from the bracket so as to have:

echo rand(1,7)

Comment: How so? PHP is the most cross-browser, as it's browser-independent.

Comment: JavaScript isn't an option, I'm trying to avoid non-PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better approach to doing this

```
<?php
 $number = rand(1,7);
 echo '<img src="http://www.example.com/site_gfx/headers/header_' . $number . 'png" width="980" height="230" alt="Example Site" />'
?>
```

There may be an issue with using the `<?php` tag inside of another tag.

Comment: Don't need (shouldn't actually) to escape double-quotes inside single quotes. That will render as exactly \".

Comment: @EvilPheonix He has a opening PHP tag `<?php` in his answer, but did not escape it, so S.O. strips it (and everything after it) from the content of his answer.

Comment: @Tieson T. Good point, my mistake, the escape characters for the double quotes should be removed.